# Is there any way to specify alternate font in JIMP?

Tags: javascript, fonts, typeerror, jimp

I'm using image.print function of JIMP and the font I'm using doesn't support languages other than English (It just returns `???`). I was wondering if there is any way that, in JIMP, I can specify an alternative font so that if first font doesn't contain that particular text then the second font will be applied? I'm trying it via this code

```js
jimp.loadFont("./Want-coffee-black.fnt", jimp.FONT_SANS_8_BLACK).then((font) => {
// do thing
})
```

But it's giving me an error called :

```
.../node_modules/@jimp/plugin-print/dist/index.js:152
         cb(null, {
         ^
[TypeError: cb is not a function]
```